# Clicking on internet url in Excel starts IE (Ok) but minimizes Excel: how do I keep Excel window as is?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, excel

It's annoying to click a url in Excel (2000) to an internet url and, when I'm done there (close IE8), restore the minimized Excel window to continue working. I would prefer to close IE and have the Excel window immediately below - where I left it.

I open an HTML page (which I've created) in Excel (2000) and everything is formatted the way I want in the correct cells and urls are clickable. Just this unexpected (to me!) behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure how to change the default behaviour but you could make a button on the excel sheet and then on the OnClick event of that button have code to follow the hyperlink and then after that restore the excel window